# Qt QLabel too slow to show a 1920x1080@25fps video

Tags: c++, qt

My method to display a video is the following:

DrawImage called, when a new image is ready, and the window is also ready to display.
I use a bool isReady what is set false before call this func and
and set true in mainwindow paintEvent override. (decide if the windows is ready)

```
void Mainview::DrawImage (char *pBuffer)
{
    lockBuffer();
    QImage image = getImageFromBuffer(); //1920x1080 RGB_888 image
    paintLabel->setImage(image); //PaintLabel pointer
    unlockBuffer();
}

void Mainview::paintEvent (QPaintEvent *e)
{
    Q_UNUSED(e);
    m_bReady = TRUE;
}
```

PaintLabel implementation (important parts):

```
void PaintLabel::setImage(QImage &image)
{
    imageData = image.scaled(this->width(), this->height()); //private QImage
    update();
}

void PaintLabel::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *ev)
{
    Q_UNUSED(ev);

    if (!m_Image.isNull())
    {
        if (isScale)
        {
        m_Image.scaled(this->width(), this->height());
        }

        QRectF target(0.0, 0.0, m_Image.width(), m_Image.height());

        // Alignment draw
        if (this->alignment() & Qt::AlignCenter)
        {
            qreal posX = this->width() / 2 - m_Image.width() / 2;
            qreal posY = this->height() / 2 - m_Image.height() / 2;
            target.setRect(posX, posY, m_Image.width(), m_Image.height());
        }

        // draw the image
        QPainter painter(this);
        painter.drawImage(target, imageData);
        painter.end();
    }
}
```

The DrawImage call takes almost 100ms which is way too much. Any idea, how to fix this problem?

Comment: Somehow I'm not surprised. `QLabel` wasn't designed for this task.

Comment: Don't use a QLabel to display video.

Comment: 1920x1080@25fps is not trivial. Btw what is the point of scaling an image if you dont use the result

Comment: This is a simplified code.  m_Image is imageData I gonna correct it.

Comment: What should I use instead QLabel ? I want something with similar difficulty.

Comment: Try `phonon`, but video with `Qt` components, in general, is not a very good idea. For performance you need to write a custom control for video using OpenGL or dx. A lot of `Qt` stuff in this area is buggy.

Comment: There is [example how to play videos](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtmultimedia/multimediawidgets-videowidget.html) with [Qt multimedia](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtmultimedia/qtmultimedia-index.html).

Comment: It only shows down,  if I use the scale function. The funny thing is,  that it worked with Qt 4.8 fine. (I use 5.2 rc now)